Square signal generated by Pico has unexpected waveform
I developed a small program for the Raspberry Pico using the Wokwi online simulator but when I tried to use the actual device it didn't work.
I started by debugging the signal generated with a logical analyzer but the waveform it reported was completely different from what I expected.
I tried to generate a simple square wave of 0.5Mhz and see if there was some logical errors inside the original program but the result was still wrong.
Here's the program (I changed the PIO program but kept everything else):
.program controller

.side_set 1 pindirs

nop side 0
nop side 1 

% c-sdk {
#include "hardware/clocks.h"

static inline void init(PIO pio, uint sm, uint offset, uint pin) {

    gpio_init(pin);
    pio_gpio_init(pio, pin);
    gpio_pull_up(pin);

    pio_sm_config c = program_get_default_config(offset);

    sm_config_set_out_shift(&c, true, true, 32);
    sm_config_set_in_shift(&c, true, false, 32);

    sm_config_set_sideset_pins(&c, pin);
    sm_config_set_in_pins(&c, pin);


    sm_config_set_jmp_pin (&c, pin);

    float div = clock_get_hz(clk_sys) / ( 1000000 );
    sm_config_set_clkdiv(&c, div);

    pio_sm_init(pio, sm, offset, &c);
    pio_sm_set_enabled(pio, sm, true);
}

#define WAIT_INPUT_OFFSET 0

static inline uint get_reset_instr (uint program_offset) {
    return pio_encode_jmp (program_offset + WAIT_INPUT_OFFSET) 
        | pio_encode_sideset (1, 0);
}
%}


On the simulator I get what I expected:

With the Pico I get a flat line:

If I try to slow the clock down I get this regular brief bursts:

The logical analyzer seems to work, I checked it against the signal this controller should respond to and I got what I expected.
I don't have experience working with electronics, am I missing something?

Is your Oscilloscope setting alright?

Yes, I tried with every frequency setting higher than 1Mhz my logic analyzer supports, same result
